# Regexp match optional group unless it's got something inside it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm playing around with this regexp: http://regex101.com/r/dL3qX1

```
!\[(.*?)\](?:\(\)|\[\])?
```

All the below strings should match. However, should the second set of brackets, that is optional, contain anything within it, the regexp should match nothing.

```
// Match
![]
![caption]
![]()
![caption]()
![][]
![caption][]

// No match
![][No match]
![caption][No match]
![](No match)
![caption](No match)
```

I should still be able to match examples that have text at the end of the line.

```
![] hello
![caption][] hi there
```

In other words, I only want a match if there is no optional group, or if there is, I only want a match if the optional group is empty (nothing between the brackets).

Is what I'm after possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer using negated class when it comes to brackets:

```
^!\[([^\[\]]*)\](?:\(\)|\[\])?$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nU3kM0)

I substituted `(.*?)` to `[^\[\]]*`, added `^` and `$` at the beginning and end respectively.

That is, if I understood what you're looking for correctly, only the first set is matching.

Comment: Similar issue to anubhava's answer. If I add anything to the end of the line, then there is no match. I'd still like to match `![caption][] hey there`

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton That means I didn't understand your question. Note that there's a difference between matching and capturing. Capturing occurs when you put stuff within parentheses `( ... )` and matching happens when the string passes the regex. Did you perhaps mean you don't want to capture `caption` when there's something in the second set of parens?

Comment: Sorry, Jerry, I added additional examples. Basically, what you gave me works perfectly but it has to be on its own line. It can't be preceded or followed by anything. Which, come to think of it, maybe alright. +1 But I'm still curious.

Comment: Actually, don't waste your time. I think this should work for my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Well, okay, I would only lastly point out that my regex is the one that captures the text within the first bracket ;)

Comment: Indeed, I only just noticed that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^!\[[^\]]*\](?:\(\)|\[\])?$
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eX0sR8

Note use of `[^\]]*` instead of `.*?` in the first square brackets which makes sure to match until very first `]`. Also better to use line start/end anchors `^ and $`

Comment: The issue with that is the line has to end. If I add additional after, then there is no match.

Comment: Provide some examples of what you want to match and then I can adjust it.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I got confused with one of your comment on Jerry's answer. Rolled back now.